# "In iOS Login page is not displayed at first but when I tilt the phone page fields are getting displayed"

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ipad, cross-domain

I am facing weird issue while accessing my application from iOS 11, The page does not load completely in the beginning, I can click on objects but not able to see the page background or field labels, but when I tilt my iPhone or zoom in the page loads completely.

I am integrating Identity Manager (Siteminder) login page inside my application frame using `response.sendRedirect()`

any help on this issue would be appriciated.

Login page is not displayed at first but when I tilt page fields are getting displayed

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)  :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the response headers to allow from different origin source to be displayed on your Page.
try using response.serHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");